# WordPress data lose after importing database into new database

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am new with Wordpress.
I have created a simple plugin to save setting for theme.

In this its working fine for saving data in database.

But am having problem when i am exporting my project Databse and import to new database.
That time all settings are gone ,i have to update theme setting every time when i am importing database to new database.

Any suggestion.
What am i doing wrong.

```
// admin page
function my_custom_settings_form()
{
    include('include/settings.php');
}

// admin menu
function my_custom_settings_menu()
{
    add_options_page('CustomSetting', ' Theme Settings', 'manage_options', 'theme-settings', 'my_custom_settings_form');
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'my_custom_settings_menu');


// register setting
function my_custom_settings_settings()
{
    register_setting('wp_sp_settings_group', 'pageSettings');
}


add_action('admin_init', 'my_custom_settings_settings');


function do_css()
{
    wp_enqueue_style('thickbox');
    wp_enqueue_style('thickbox');
}

function do_jslibs()
{
    wp_enqueue_script('editor');
    wp_enqueue_script('thickbox');
    add_action( 'admin_head', 'wp_tiny_mce' );
}

add_action('admin_print_scripts', 'do_jslibs' );
add_action('admin_print_styles', 'do_css' );


function wp_gear_manager_admin_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_media();
}

function wp_gear_manager_admin_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style('thickbox');
}

add_action('admin_print_scripts', 'wp_gear_manager_admin_scripts');
add_action('admin_print_styles', 'wp_gear_manager_admin_styles');

?>
```

include/settings.php

```
$pageSettings = get_option('pageSettings');
?>
<div class="wrap">
    <h2>Theme Settings</h2>
    <hr/>
    <?php settings_errors('', true, true); ?>
    <div class="postbox-container" id="poststuff">
        <form action="options.php" method="POST">
            <?php settings_fields('wp_sp_settings_group'); ?>

            <div class="postbox">
                <div class="handlediv" title="Click to toggle">
                    <br>
                </div>
                <h3>
                    <span>Header Logo</span>
                </h3>

                <div class="inside">
                    <table class="form-table ">
                        <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div class="uploader">
                                    <input type="text" name="pageSettings[site-logo]" id="site-logo" value="<?php echo $pageSettings['site-logo'] ; ?>" />
                                    <input class="button" type="button" name="site-logo-button" id="site-logo-button" value="Upload" />
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>

            <p class="submit">
                <input type="submit" value="Save Changes" class="button button-primary" id="submit"
                       name="submit">
            </p>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Best way to Make a exact copy of database without losing any info is by going to the database itself and export everything.  Then import the data into the new website setup your WP config. Once done, go into the database and change your wp-setting data table for values
related to **WEBSITE URL**

There should be two places you need to change.

Answer (score 0):

Jay has the right answer, but I think off the top of my head the table is wp_options rather than settings. The things you need to change are "siteurl" and "home"